# If $a\equiv b \ \mathrm{mod}(n)$ and $m|n$, then $a\equiv b \ \mathrm{mod}(m)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is this correct:

If $a\equiv b \ \mathrm{mod}(n)$ and $m|n$, then $a\equiv b \ \mathrm{mod}(m)$.

Let $a=q_{1}n+r$, $b=q_{2}n+r$ and $n=mc$. Then we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{q_{1}mc+r -(q_{2}mc+r)}{mc}=\frac{q_{1}m+r -(q_{2}m+r)}{m},
\end{align*}
which imply that $a\equiv b \ \mathrm{mod}(m)$.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct. One can establish the result more simply, or at least using fewer symbols. For note that $a\equiv b\pmod{n}$ **means** that $n$ divides $b-a$.

Since $m$ divides $n$, it follows that $m$ divides $b-a$, that is, $a\equiv b\pmod{m}$.

**Remark:** You handled the calculation perfectly correctly. However, in my experience, when one is beginning to do Number Theory, it is best to avoid calculations with "fractions."  Writing $x=yz$ can be safer than writing $z=\frac{x}{y}$.

Comment: Thx, - ofcourse!

Answer (score 3):

Yes we can also see the result by:
$$a\equiv b \ \mathrm{mod}(n)\iff a=b+kn=b+k\alpha m=b+k' m\iff a\equiv b \ \mathrm{mod}(m)$$